# Incremental Game c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

My name is John and I'm trying to do basic Incremental game in c# WFA

I managed to do clickable button that adds value to my money
Clickable button which upgrade the value, decrease my money by price and increase the price (If i have enough money) else just show messagebox

I want to add the idle like money per second but still be able to use buttons SO- everysecond x money will be added and i still can use buttons even when it is not necessary

Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void Ref() 
    {
        lbl_Money.Text = money.ToString();   
        lbl_PerTap.Text = upgrade.ToString(); 
        lbl_Price.Text = price.ToString();  
    }

    int money = 0;            
    int upgrade = 1;          
    int price = 64;            

    public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ref(); 
    }

    private void Tap_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        money += upgrade;
        Ref(); 
    }

    private void Upgrade_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(money >= price) 
        { //Ano
            upgrade += 1; 
            money -= price;  
            price += (price / 16); 
        }
        else
        { //NE
            MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Money!");
        }
        Ref(); 
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic Timer (fix it to suit your needs):

Add this in the class:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
```

and this in the constructor:

```
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
```

And this, too, in the class:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    money += upgrade;
}
```